# Retrieving Record from Top Level of a Nested For Loop

Tags: apex, trigger

Still very much a trigger noob, so if there's a more efficient way to accomplish this, please let me know. Basically, this trigger should be creating a new 'In' inventory transaction every time an 'Out' transaction is created in one Production Order - it should be related to the right Production Order as well as have the correct inventory stage (which is located on the 'Out' transaction's production order object.

It all seems to work fine, except for the assignment of the production order inventory stage. My hunch is that there's something I'm missing around assigning values out of the scope of the for loop you're in. Anywho - here's the code, note the Inventory Stage assignment in the inner for loop, that's where my issues are. Thanks in advance.

```
trigger inventoryManagementTrigger on Inventory_Transaction__c (before insert) {

List<Inventory_Transaction__c> toClone = new List<Inventory_Transaction__c>();
Set<Id> shiftIds = new Set<Id>();

for ( Inventory_Transaction__c invTransaction : Trigger.new ) {
    shiftIds.add( invTransaction.Production_Shift__r.id );
}

List<Transaction__c> thisWeeksShifts = new List<Transaction__c> ([SELECT Id, Name, Inventory_Stage__c 
                                                                  FROM Transaction__c 
                                                                  WHERE Shift_Start__c = THIS_WEEK]);


for(Inventory_Transaction__c invTrans : Trigger.new) {
    if (invTrans.Type__c == 'Out') {
    String invStage = invTrans.Production_Shift__r.Inventory_Stage__c;   
        for ( Transaction__c t : thisWeeksShifts ) {
            if (t.Inventory_Stage__c == invTrans.Inventory_Stage__c) {
                Inventory_Transaction__c invTransNew = invTrans.clone(false, true, false, false);
                invTransNew.Production_Shift__c = t.Id;
                invTransNew.Inventory_Stage__c = invStage;
                invTransNew.Type__c = 'In';
                toClone.add(invTransNew);

        }

        try {
            insert toClone;
        } catch (system.DmlException e) {
            system.debug(e);
            for (Inventory_Transaction__c i : toClone) {
                    i.adderror('There was a problem creating the related IN Transaction' + e);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing? any exception?

Comment: Sorry - the Inventory_Stage__c field on the created Inventory_Transaction is not getting assigned to the cloned Inventory_Transaction__c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zac,

there are few things i noticed that can be changed / improved in this trigger..

1. you cannot access related object fields from the trigger.new context variable without querying for it.

so the **Production_Shift__r.id** in the first for loop and **Production_Shift__r.Inventory_Stage__c** in the second for loop will all be null

2. also it seems you have the Inventory_Stage__c field on both the Inventory Transaction object and Production Shift object..

if they are the same then you can directly use the one on the Inventory Transaction object. since you are doing a deep clone, you should get the value automatically..

3. i would suggest to move the insert statement out of the for loop to **bulkify** it.
4. you are not using the shiftIds list collection.. i m not sure why you need it.
5. you can further optimise by removing the inner for loop and use a Map to get the shift based on stage.. [i haven't done this]

so the simplified version will look something like below..

```
    trigger inventoryManagementTrigger on Inventory_Transaction__c (before insert) {

        List<Inventory_Transaction__c> toClone = new List<Inventory_Transaction__c>();

        List<Transaction__c> thisWeeksShifts = new List<Transaction__c> ([SELECT Id, Name, Inventory_Stage__c 
                                                                  FROM Transaction__c 
                                                                  WHERE Shift_Start__c = THIS_WEEK]);

        for(Inventory_Transaction__c invTrans : Trigger.new) {
          if (invTrans.Type__c == 'Out') {
              for ( Transaction__c t : thisWeeksShifts ) {
                 if (t.Inventory_Stage__c == invTrans.Inventory_Stage__c) {
                    Inventory_Transaction__c invTransNew = invTrans.clone(false, true, false, false);
                    invTransNew.Production_Shift__c = t.Id;
                    invTransNew.Type__c = 'In';
                    toClone.add(invTransNew);
                    break;
                    }
                }
             }
        }

        insert toClone;

    }
```

Comment: Yep, I should have explained this a little more 1, 2.) I'm trying to reach out of the nested for loop (Transaction) and assign a field from the current record from the upper loop (Inventory Transaction) to the cloned Inventory Stage field - this is because the field on the Transaction object is the current stage and the cloned Inventory Transaction Stage field is where the transaction is coming from 3.) Done - just messed up my brackets, thanks for catching that. 4.) I need to get rid of that, I was trying different methods to get the related shifts. 5.) I'll give this a shot - thanks!